# How to retrieve Rows Values on Google analytics API V4 - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to migrate my tiny report from V3 to V4, but I have found an issue which is annoying me and making me feel like I'm totally dumb.

So I just took the example code at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js
and change a couple of things, and it works, it runs the report. But when I try to retrieve the data from the different rows with the below function:

```js
function displayResults(response) {
    var Objeto = response.result["reports"];
    var Filas01 = Objeto["data"];
  console.log(Objeto);
  console.log(Filas01);
                                   }
```

Objeto shows everything within .reports

But Filas01 shows undefined, I have tried to retrieve reponse.results.reports.data.rows;

And several variations but it says undefined all the time,

I have no clue why it was working on V3 and is not on V4,

Please any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There are [samples](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#multiple_date_ranges) of how to make requests and precess the response in various languages. But specifically here is a simple **JavaScript** function which processes the results into a table:

```
function handleReportingResults(response) {
  if (!response.code) {
    outputToPage('Query Success');
    for( var i = 0, report; report = response.reports[ i ]; ++i )
    {
      output.push('<h3>All Rows Of Data</h3>');
      if (report.data.rows && report.data.rows.length) {
        var table = ['<table>'];

        // Put headers in table.
        table.push('<tr><th>', report.columnHeader.dimensions.join('</th><th>'), '</th>');
        table.push('<th>Date range #</th>');

        for (var i=0, header; header = report.columnHeader.metricHeader.metricHeaderEntries[i]; ++i) {
          table.push('<th>', header.name, '</th>');
        }

        table.push('</tr>');

        // Put cells in table.
        for (var rowIndex=0, row; row = report.data.rows[rowIndex]; ++rowIndex) {
          for(var dateRangeIndex=0, dateRange; dateRange = row.metrics[dateRangeIndex]; ++dateRangeIndex) {
            // Put dimension values
            table.push('<tr><td>', row.dimensions.join('</td><td>'), '</td>');
            // Put metric values for the current date range
            table.push('<td>', dateRangeIndex, '</td><td>', dateRange.values.join('</td><td>'), '</td></tr>');
          }
        }
        table.push('</table>');

        output.push(table.join(''));
      } else {
        output.push('<p>No rows found.</p>');
      }
    }
    outputToPage(output.join(''));

  } else {
    outputToPage('There was an error: ' + response.message);
  }
}
```

I would also recommend taking the time to review the overal structure of the response in the [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#Report)

Comment: Thanks Matt, I tried the example but is not working. Is there any difference between displayResults and handleReportingResults functions? I couldn't find anything on the documentation. I tried to extract the data from the rows with report.data.rows but didn't work too.